# Send variable to linker via source code

Tags: c, linker, config

In some header I've got FLASH_BASE and FLASH_SIZE makro and I would like to use them in linker script. I have tried something like this:

```
    // main.c
    long CURRENT_FLASH_START = FLASH_BASE + FLASH_SIZE / 2;
    int main(void) {
        return 0;
    }

    // s_FLASH.ld
    MEMORY
    {
        RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 48K
        RAM2 (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 16K
        FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = CURRENT_FLASH_START, LENGTH = 256K
    }
```

But in map file I see that place for code in flash starts at address 0. Is there any possibilty to use variable from makro (from .h file) in linker script file? I use Ac6 STM32 MCU GCC with Gnu Make builder.

Comment: If and how this might work, is 100% depending on your compiler toolset.

Comment: So what compiler/toolchain are you using?

Comment: Ac6 STM32 MCU GCC, Gnu Make builder

Comment: Usually it is done the opposite way. The C program can import symbols from linker script, which is making perfect sense, as the linker is the primary source of memory layout.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. is right, and it is done this way for many reasons. Just do it the ES way.